# how to see all files on external hard drive

Tags: external-disk, disk-space, macos

I have 200g of content on my 500g External Hard Drive but according to "get info" 471g of space is being used up, what am I not seeing?
(To arrive at 200g I manually added all folder sizes using 'get info') Could it be hidden trash?

Comment: There are hidden files that you can see in Finder if you type this in Terminal: `defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool YES`. I might have had the same problem with my USB that there was a hidden folder with things that I deleted ages ago.

Comment: Did you recently delete things from it?  Your user Trash (~/Trash) might just need to be deleted.

Comment: Cheers The Bro21, I did try putting that script into terminal and relaunching finder but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it was simply that the trash was not emptied: I have learnt that to remove items from an External Hard Drive I must empty the trash *while it is connected*!  Otherwise the files remain hidden but using space up on the drive.

Answer (score 2):

a simple way without using terminal:
- Hold down CMD-Shift-. (dot)
- All the hidden files will become visible
- Hold down CMD-Shift-. (dot) a second time to hide the files again

Answer (score 0):

You can try either of these commands

```
    sudo ls -l /Volumes/VOLUMENAME
```

or

```
    sudo du -ck /Volumes/VOLUMENAME
```

change VOLUMENAME to the appropriate name.

Comment: Thanks fd0, I am not very computer smart, I put one of those commands into terminal and it said: WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss
or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your
typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.

To proceed, enter your password, or type Ctrl-C to abort.